# VBA: Write array to sheet in a block (one memory access)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, optimization, variant

I have a large array (45000 elements) that i need to write down in an excel sheet. However this is taking way to long when looping over the values (requesting a memory access for each value)

(I have already disabled features like screen updating)

I've found some ways to do it using the Variant type (french : https://www.lecfomasque.com/vba-rediger-des-macros-plus-rapides/) However i must be messing up at some point, see example code

```
Sub test()
    Dim table(4) As Variant
    Dim writeArray() As Variant


    table(0) = 0
    table(1) = 1
    table(2) = 2
    table(3) = 3
    table(4) = 4

    writeArray = table

    'Supposed to write 0 to A1, 1 to A2,... but not working that way
    Range("A1:A5").Value = writeArray

End Sub
```

This code writes only the first value (0) to the whole range, even if the variant writearray contains also the other values (1,2,3,4).

Any idea (without a memory request for each value) on how to solve this is welcome, Thank you ^-^

EDIT (SOLUTION)-----------------------

Paul's (transpose) and Mikku's (2D-array) solutions seem to work and both provide an tenfold reduction of execution time in my case. The transpose is slighly faster on average.

Comment: Both answers work, but would have to be adjusted for the fact that your subscripts start at zero - ubound-lbound+1?

Comment: Otherwise you miss the last row.

Comment: @TomSharpe - The text I've put in my answer actually comes from the site which discusses the use of ranged dimensions - e.g. `ReDim Arr(1 to 10, 1 To 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [this site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) I found this useful little piece...

```
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Range("K1")
Destination.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
```

You can transpose the array when writing to the worksheet:

```
Set Destination = Range("K1")
Destination.Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Well a 2-D array can do that**

```
Sub test()

    Dim table(0 To 4, 1 To 1) As Variant

    table(0, 1) = 0
    table(1, 1) = 1
    table(2, 1) = 2
    table(3, 1) = 3
    table(4, 1) = 4


    Range("A1:A5") = table


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that 1D array corresponds to a *row* in the sheet. So you can put

```
Range("A1:E1") = table
```

and it works fine.

If you want to put your array into a column, the easiest way is to use transpose as mentioned by @Paul:

```
writeArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(table)
```

which gives you a 2D array with five rows and 1 column.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim table(0 To 4) As Variant
    Dim writeArray() As Variant


    table(0) = 0
    table(1) = 1
    table(2) = 2
    table(3) = 3
    table(4) = 4

    writeArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(table)

    Debug.Print ("ubound=" & UBound(writeArray, 1))
    Debug.Print ("ubound=" & UBound(writeArray, 2))

    Range("A1:A5") = writeArray
    Range("A1:E1") = table
End Sub
```

[image]